# How to add -d JSONString='{} in postman

Tags: json, api, postman, zoho

I want to send a API request, but it keeps returning invalid JSON string. I'm using Postman and putting the request in the body of the POST call but it keeps failing. Any suggestions?

Here is the sample request or the services api docs

`$ curl https://inventory.zoho.com/api/v1/packages?authtoken=********************&organization_id=10234695
-d JSONString='{
    "package_number": "PA-00001",
    "date": "2017-01-11T00:00:00.000Z",
    "line_items": [
        {
            "so_line_item_id": 504366000000062000,
            "quantity": 2
        }
    ],
    "notes": "notes"
}'`

Comment: Consider removing the authtoken from your post, as those should remain private. Can you post a picture of how you put your JSON inside postman? What type of headers did you configure?

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens. You can also edit out the info and flag your post for a moderator to redact the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

send it as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, it need `salesorder_id` and change date format to `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
salesorder_id | XXXXXX
JSONString | {"package_number" : ..... "date": "2019-01-11" ....}
```